# json deserialization fail for valid format

Tags: java, json, date

I have a json file with a date like this:

```
{
...
  "dob":"20001010",
  "registerdate":"20001010121212",
...
}
```

i am using in class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
... some other
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyyMMdd
    public java.util.Date dob; // this works

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    public java.util.Date registerdate;
}
```

then in my test i use Gson to convert the file

```
User user = new Gson().fromJson("user.json", User.class);
```

but when this run, i get:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 20001010121212
```

I treid with: yyyyMMddHHmmss or YYYYMMddHHmmss or YYYYMMDDHHmmss same results

pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Please provide version of Gson lib

Comment: im using: 2.8.5

Comment: `@JsonFormat` is a Jackson annotation, not a Gson annotation. If you already have Jackson on the classpath, use that to parse the Json text to `User` object.

Comment: @Andreas not sure what to do then how can i do ?

Comment: @yenk I already told you: *Use Jackson to parse.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically **com.google.gson.Gson** does not recognize annotation **com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat** (two different libs)

Here is another solution using just ObjectMapper from fasterxml lib

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{\"dob\":\"20001010121212\"}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        User user = objectMapper.readValue(json, User.class);
        System.out.println(user.dob);
    }
}

class User implements Serializable {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    public Date dob;
}
```

Comment: why I get: Tue Oct 10 05:12:12 PDT .. I should get: Tue Oct 10 12:12:12 PDT

Comment: I got it to work, didnt realize PST vs GMT duh ! thanks for your help (way better helper than @Andreas)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GSON, you need to parse date something like

```java
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class GSONExample {

    private static String json = "{\r\n" + "  \"dob\":\"20001010121212\"\r\n" + "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").create();
        ItemDob itemDob = gson.fromJson(json, ItemDob.class);
        System.out.println(itemDob.getDob());
    }

}

class ItemDob {
    private Date dob;

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

Output

> Tue Oct 10 12:12:12 IST 2000

**EDIT**
If you want to specify date formats using annotations, use jackson. For eg,

```java
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonExample {

    private static String json = "{\r\n" + 
            "  \"dob\": \"20001010121212\"\r\n" + 
            "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        ItemDob itemDob = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, ItemDob.class);
        System.out.println(itemDob.getDob());
    }

}

class ItemDob {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    private Date dob;

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

Output:

> Tue Oct 10 17:42:12 IST 2000

Comment: will also work if i have other dates with different format ?

Comment: @yenk No, so [*use Jackson*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979032/json-deserialization-fail-for-valid-format?noredirect=1#comment106073669_59979032).

Comment: Yes, you would have to create new Gson object using GsonBuilder for each date format. But if you want to use annotation based date formats, use jackson.